# TeamCity - Git push from agent

Tags: git, push, teamcity, agent

I've got a TeamCity server set up to checkout src from GitHub on the agents using "Default Private Key" and a config file in .ssh that looks like this:

```
Host git@github.com
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa.shop
    StrictHostKeyChecking no

Host github.com
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa.shop
    StrictHostKeyChecking no
```

and this works fine.
Now i want to push from the agents.
However when i do this the push command hangs due to user input:

```
The authenticity of host 'github.com (192.30.252.130' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprints is 'xxx....xxx'
Are you sure you want to continue (yes/no)
Warning: Permently added '' to known hosts.
Connection closed by 192.30.252.130
Fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly.
```

If i do this manually it still fails with permission denied no matter wether i type yes/no.

The "Default Private Key" has read/write permissions accoring to github, so im a bit lost.
Only thing i have observed is that the github ip looks very local, but how can that be when the agent has just done a agent side checkout? Could this be a firewall?

Can anyone explain to me what im missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out there was a rather big catch with the setup. 
Apperently for reason i do not quite understand the user context/profile changed once i called git. 
This would change the homedir.
This can be verified by looking at the Git etc file which does the profile change called: profile:

```
# Set up USER's home directory
if [ -z "$HOME" -o ! -d "$HOME" ]; then
  HOME="$HOMEDRIVE$HOMEPATH"
  if [ -z "$HOME" -o ! -d "$HOME" ]; then
    HOME="$USERPROFILE"
  fi
fi

if [ ! -d "$HOME" ]; then
    printf "\n\033[31mERROR: HOME directory '$HOME' doesn't exist!\033[m\n\n"
    echo "This is an error which might be related to msysGit issue 108."
    echo "You might want to set the environment variable HOME explicitly."
    printf "\nFalling back to \033[31m/ ($(cd / && pwd -W))\033[m.\n\n"
    HOME=/
fi

# normalize HOME to unix path
HOME="$(cd "$HOME" ; pwd)"
```

I fixed this issue by forcing the home dir to current user as so:

```
set HOME=%env.USERPROFILE%
```

The problem was in an init script of git.

Moreover I had to modifiy the config to:

```
Host webshop_github
HostName github.com
User git
PreferredAuthentications publickey
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa.shop
```

Comment: That's really weird. I've stuck with the same problem on Windows agent. And I've solved it using your solution. Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Actually I've dipped a bit further and found another solution thanks to @Christian Mikkelsen and answers in this thread: [git.cmd vs git.exe - what is the difference and which one should be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8947140/git-cmd-vs-git-exe-what-is-the-difference-and-which-one-should-be-used).

You just should not use the original `git.exe` when manually working with git, but the wrappers - `gitk.cmd` or `cmd\git.exe`. Please note that `cmd\git.exe` isn't the same as `bin\git.exe`. Teamcity itself uses `bin\git.exe` as it knows how to work with it. But if you work with git manually you should use `cmd\git.exe`.

The problem you have to solve is how to pass the path to `cmd\git.exe` into your script. I support it can be done using custom parameters or perhaps overriding the `env.TEAMCITY_GIT_PATH` before executing your script.