# Error with Git installation

Tags: git, version-control, github, path

I just installed Git with the intention of using it from my command line. And everytime i use a git command, I get the following output, seems like i get the right output AND some weird errors.

```
>C:\Users\Harish Kumar>git --version
>'chcp' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
>git version 1.7.11.msysgit.0
>'chcp' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Here are my path variables just in case:

User Variables:

```
 C:\RailsInstaller\Git\cmd;C:\RailsInstaller\Ruby1.9.3\bin;C:\Users\Harish Kumar\AppData\Roaming\npm\
```

System Variables:

```
 C:\MinGW\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_33\bin;
 C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;
 C:\Program Files(x86)\Git\cmd;C:\RailsInstaller\Git\cmd;C:\RailsInstaller\Ruby1.9.3\bin;
 C:\Users\Harish Kumar\AppData\Roaming\npm\
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8142058/chcp-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command-operable-program-or

Answer (score 0):

You should use git via msysgit. This will have all paths setup.