# C++ ':chcp' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: c++, windows

(*Before the question: I would appreciate if someone wouldn't flag this thread as a duplicate because as much as I searched there wasn't anything close to my problem, only other programming languages and compilers or different OS's*)

I'm using Dev C++ and I was after debuging a program with greek characters (`system("chcp 1253");`)at the output, but when I ran it, all the characters were unreadable and this message above was seen:

[image]

Based on some pretty close questions on the web ([here](https://resource.dopus.com/t/chcp-error-running-batch-file/5219) and [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/railsinstaller/w7i1GFSkQqo) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8142058/chcp-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command-operable-program-or)) I though that my path was also broken, so I checked it out with "check chcp" on cmd, where it showed the proper path (c:\Windows\System32\chcp.com).

*[screenshot here](http://i63.tinypic.com/2n9kozp.png)*

Has anyone else has come up with the same issue?

Comment: What happens when you run "check chcp" from your program using system?  Or, similiarly, "where chcp"?

Comment: "check chcp" gives me the same kind of error. I found a work-around where I put the whole path of chcp in my code [ system("C:\\Windows\\System32\\chcp.com 1253"); ], but i want to know what caused it and how can i fix it.

Comment: yes it just happened to me with Dev-C. The weird thing is that I had installed TDM-GCC-32 first and then an empty Dev-C (without compiler) and this problem with dchp did not exist. However, as I had a problem with debugger, I uninstalled everything and reinstalled Dev-C with compiler and this error showed up. With your solution, it is tackled but I still wonder why it happened.. It's all Greek to me.

Comment: @YannisDran if I had to guess, I'd say that some software on your machine messed with your system's path and environment variables. A new compiler or a removal of another one might be responsible. Windows are very keen to these kind of 'quirks'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To re-set the path of chcp to the compiler, I simply had to type the whole path from the Windows folder into my program:

```
system("C:\\Windows\\System32\\chcp.com 1253");
```

This also works without the full path:

```
system("chcp.com 1253");
```

And then I had to get rid of the ".com" portion of it, making it:

```
system("chcp 1253");
```

Still, kind of a work-around but time-saving and risk-free.

Comment: Works fine using Visual Studio on my machine.  Sounds like the `PATHEXT` environment variable has gone missing somehow.

Comment: Netbeans kinda screwed up my paths, so I will try to be careful next time.