# How to fix ' ''chcp'is not recognized as an internal or external command...' while activating Opencv Env?

Tags: python, opencv, anaconda

I'm installing **Opencv 3** on Windows(8.1). I already have **Anaconda3** and I'm getting the above mentioned error while **activating Opencv-env**.
 When I researched, I found it may be a PATH problem. But I didn't got any solution.

```
(opencv-env) C:\Users\admin\Anaconda3\envs\opencv-env>activate opencv-env
'chcp' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
 operable program or batch file.
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of ['chcp' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file. on a Windows PC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8142058/chcp-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command-operable-program-or)

Comment: I tried that one.. But didn't work :( @KenY-N