# why i Can't install Google app-engine-java

Tags: google-app-engine, cmd, google-cloud-platform, installation

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BFFYe.png)Every time i run "gcloud components install app-engine-java", i get

"Restarting command:

$ gcloud components install app-engine-java"

this is happening even when i run remove or update components.

i tried add google cloud to my system and user variable
i tried reinstalling google cloud and restarting my pc
i tried to run it as an administrator
i tried a different cmd alternative

this is the output after trying to install app-engine-java

> > >
> >     Restarting command:

$ gcloud components install app-engine-java <<<

Answer (score 1):

The message below is working properly and it should open a new CLI installing the gcloud component

```
Restarting command:
$ gcloud components install app-engine-java
```

The real error is  `'chcp' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.`

There is a problem with your environment variables as the path cannot find the `chcp` command which is used by Windows.

Below is similar issue with a solution.

- ['chcp' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file. on a Windows PC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8142058/chcp-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command-operable-program-or)