# Need to fix the error of cannot update conda all package?

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I have been using Anaconda 2019.07 for python 3.7 on windows 10. And I cannot update all package using

```
conda update --all
```

The error is as below

```
ERROR conda.core.link:_execute(696): An error occurred while installing package 'defaults::ipykernel-5.1.2-py37h39e3cac_0'.
Rolling back transaction: done

LinkError: post-link script failed for package defaults::ipykernel-5.1.2-py37h39e3cac_0
location of failed script: C:\Users\johnn\Anaconda3\Scripts\.ipykernel-post-link.bat
==> script messages <==
<None>
==> script output <==
stdout:
stderr: 'chcp' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'chcp' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'chcp' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

return code: 1
```

How can I fix this problem? Please help.

I have even removed all anaconda and have a fresh installation but the error is still there.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ['chcp' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file. on a Windows PC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8142058/chcp-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command-operable-program-or). Obvious a different command, but try the things in the answer, e.g., check `PATH`, make sure `where chcp` works, etc.

Comment: This is not the same issue as shown in the duplicate.  It looks like a bug: https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/11269

Comment: @Trenton_M still could be a duplicate, e.g., both could have similar `PATH` configuration issues. We need feedback from the OP to say they tried the suggested solutions and they didn't fix it.

Comment: I think it's like  @trenton_m mentioned, I also have tried to find the solution but it's not work

Comment: You can find older distributions here: https://repo.continuum.io/archive/