# Deeplabcut installing _ conda evironment

Tags: anaconda, conda, deeplab

I am trying to install deeplabcut. I am following instructions.

However, while I was trying to do this, "conda env create -f DLC-CPU.yaml".
It occurs some error below. Is there anyone who knows how to fix?

---

```
> (base) C:\Users\GunAhn>cd
> C:\Users\GunAhn\Desktop\my_project\DeepLabCut\conda-environments
> 
> (base)
> C:\Users\GunAhn\Desktop\my_project\DeepLabCut\conda-environments>conda
> env create -f DLC-CPU.yaml Collecting package metadata
> (repodata.json): done Solving environment: done
> 
> Downloading and Extracting Packages bleach-3.1.4         | 114 KB    |
> #################################### | 100% qtconsole-4.7.3      | 94 KB     | #################################### | 100% Preparing
> transaction: done Verifying transaction: done Executing transaction: \
> b'Enabling nb_conda_kernels...\nStatus: enabled\n' / b'Enabling
> notebook extension nb_conda/main...\n      - Validating: ok\nEnabling
> tree extension nb_conda/tree...\n      - Validating: ok\nEnabling:
> nb_conda\n- Writing config:
> C:\\Users\\GunAhn\\anaconda3\\envs\\DLC-CPU\\etc\\jupyter\n    -
> Validating...\n      nb_conda 2.2.1 ok\n' done ERROR
> conda.core.link:_execute(700): An error occurred while installing
> package 'defaults::qt-5.9.7-vc14h73c81de_0'. Rolling back transaction:
> done
> 
> LinkError: post-link script failed for package
> defaults::qt-5.9.7-vc14h73c81de_0 location of failed script:
> C:\Users\GunAhn\anaconda3\envs\DLC-CPU\Scripts\.qt-post-link.bat
> ==> script messages <== <None>
> ==> script output <== stdout:         1 file(s) copied.
> 
> stderr: 'chcp' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
> operable program or batch file. 'chcp' is not recognized as an
> internal or external command, operable program or batch file. 'chcp'
> is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program
> or batch file.
> 
> return code: 1
> 
> ()
> 
> 
> (base)
> C:\Users\GunAhn\Desktop\my_project\DeepLabCut\conda-environments>
```

Comment: your error message is really messed up. Can you please check the formatting? I recommend to copy/paste the complete error, then highlight and hit the code formatting button (`{}`)

Comment: Does this answer your question? ['chcp' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file. on a Windows PC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8142058/chcp-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command-operable-program-or)

Comment: I have too many errors. {ERROR > conda.core.link:_execute(700): An error occurred while installing package 'defaults::qt-5.9.7-vc14h73c81de_0'. } is first error I got.

After then I got another error like this {LinkError: post-link script failed for package}
.