# Install spyder inside environment

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, spyder, virtual-environment

I'm trying to install spyder in an environment with the command `conda install spyder` but I got the error:

```
> ERROR conda.core.link:_execute(700): An error occurred while
> installing package 'defaults::qt-5.9.7-vc14h73c81de_0'. Rolling back
> transaction: done

LinkError: post-link script failed for package defaults::qt-5.9.7-vc14h73c81de_0
location of failed script: C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\SimPEG1401\Scripts\.qt-post-link.bat
==> script messages <==
<None>
==> script output <==
stdout:         1 file(s) copied.

stderr: 'chcp' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'chcp' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'chcp' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

return code: 1

()
```

Does someone know how to overcome that?

Comment: Please do not share information as images unless absolutely necessary. See: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/.

Comment: Looks like this issue: https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/1491

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this answer from Spyder group:

> this is a conda issue caused by a missing variable in the PATH when
> trying to install packages that depend on Qt, for example Spyder (you
> can see the issue [here](https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/10949)).
>
> Following this you will need to setup your PATH env variable with the
> correct values as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8142058/chcp-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command-operable-program-or/8143664#8143664). The missing executable (chcp) should
> be located at C:\Windows\System32\chcp.com so probably in your path
> the %SystemRoot%\system32 string is missing.