# I can't even install qt locally

Tags: anaconda, conda

Here is my problem about miniconda installing qt.
C:\Users\wenka\miniconda3\pkgs>conda install --use-local qt-5.9.7-vc14h73c81de_0.tar.bz2
Preparing transaction: done
Verifying transaction: done
Executing transaction: done
ERROR conda.core.link:_execute(699): An error occurred while installing package '::qt-5.9.7-vc14h73c81de_0'.
Rolling back transaction: done`enter code here`

```
enter code here

LinkError: post-link script failed for package <unknown>::qt-5.9.7-vc14h73c81de_0
location of failed script: C:\Users\wenka\miniconda3\Scripts\.qt-post-link.bat
==> script messages <==
<None>
==> script output <==
stdout:         1 file(s) copied.

stderr: 'chcp' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'chcp' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'chcp' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

I have tried to install qt with conda install qt5.9.7,but failed.

Comment: Try figuring out why isn't `chcp` recognized. That is a standard DOS command that the Qt post-link script is attempting to use (has to do with language configuration). Maybe try opening a command prompt and running `where chcp`. Could you add the output of `conda info` to your question?

Answer (score 0):

I have experimented the same issue before while attempting to set up a virtual environment. This worked for me:
The problem might lie with your System variables, which have been set incorrectly.
Here is how you solve the issue:

1. Check if your PATH environment variable is setup properly. Any system should have atleast the below on Path:

`%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;`

2. Add it to Path if it is not there. This should fix the issue

Source & more details here: ['chcp' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file. on a Windows PC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8142058/chcp-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command-operable-program-or)