# ERROR conda.core.link:_execute(699): An error occurred while installing package 'defaults::qt-5.9.7-vc14h73c81de_0'. Rolling back transaction: done

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, conda, miniconda

I wanted to install the matplotlib package using conda.

The actual result was the following:

```
ERROR conda.core.link:_execute(699): An error occurred while installing package 'defaults::qt-5.9.7-vc14h73c81de_0'.
```

I expected successful installation of matplotlib, so that I could run it on my jupyter notebook.

I used the following command for installing the package:

```
conda install matplotlib
```

here is the error that I got:

```
Preparing transaction: done
Verifying transaction: done
Executing transaction: done
ERROR conda.core.link:_execute(699): An error occurred while installing package 'defaults::qt-5.9.7-vc14h73c81de_0'.
Rolling back transaction: done

LinkError: post-link script failed for package defaults::qt-5.9.7-vc14h73c81de_0
location of failed script: C:\Users\Asus\Desktop\env\Scripts\.qt-post-link.bat
==> script messages <==
<None>
==> script output <==
stdout:         1 file(s) copied.

stderr: 'chcp' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'chcp' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'chcp' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

return code: 1

()
```

Please help me with this, as I'm able to install other packages like pandas, numpy, etc, but its happening only in the case of matplotlib package.
Thank you.

Comment: If you have anaconda, then matplotlib is already installed by default, unless this is miniconda and you're installing on a raspberry pi

Comment: Yes, this is miniconda.

Answer (score 3):

Never seen this error before but did you try installing matplotlib via conda while in admin mode?

To do that open your code editor as admin. This usually opens it with additional saving rights if your target download location (most of the time the sidepackages folder of your used environment) is behind a security-rule to prevent unauthorized saving to that location.

Speaking of which this could also be caused by breaking your package dependencies. Did you activate a virtual environment before starting to code? A virtual env is good for saving you a lot of trouble to keep track of dependencies and packages possibly changing theirs causing your code to break when you update.

Answer (score 3):

I have experimented the same issue before while attempting to install a different package. The problem lies with your System variables, which have been set incorrectly.
Here is how you solve the issue:

1. Check if your PATH environment variable is setup properly. Any system should have atleast the below on Path:

`%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;`

2. Add it to Path if it is not there. This should fix the issue

Source & more details here: ['chcp' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file. on a Windows PC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8142058/chcp-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command-operable-program-or)

Comment: For people as stupid as me... if you have removed the .COM extension from PATHEXT for the lulz... maybe put it back in ;)

Answer (score 2):

I solved this by

```
conda clean --all
```

after that, reinstall the package