# Error occurs when installing mss with conda

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I would like to install `mss` from here:

```
https://mss.readthedocs.io/en/stable/installation.html
```

After the line:

```
mamba install mss=4.0.2 python
```

the following error message occurs:

```
ERROR conda.core.link:_execute(699): An error occurred while installing package 'conda-forge::qt-5.12.9-h5909a2a_4'.
Rolling back transaction: done

LinkError: post-link script failed for package conda-forge::qt-5.12.9-h5909a2a_4
location of failed script: C:\Users\mike\Anaconda3\envs\mssenv\Scripts\.qt-post-link.bat
==> script messages <==
<None>
==> script output <==
stdout:         1 Datei(en) kopiert.

stderr: Der Befehl "chcp" ist entweder falsch geschrieben oder
konnte nicht gefunden werden.
Der Befehl "chcp" ist entweder falsch geschrieben oder
konnte nicht gefunden werden.
Der Befehl "chcp" ist entweder falsch geschrieben oder
konnte nicht gefunden werden.

return code: 1

()
```

How can I resolve this error?

Comment: Have you modified your PATH in any way? Can you run `chcp` from your normal cmd?

Comment: Does this answer the question? https://stackoverflow.com/q/8142058/570918