# I was trying to install cudatoolkit on my anaconda to work with tensorflow but It didn't work

Tags: python, tensorflow, anaconda, cudnn

I was trying to download cudatoolkit on my environment variable on anaconda using this command
(conda install -c conda-forge cudatoolkit=11.2) and when it finishes downloading and start extracting this error shows:
"""
Executing transaction: - "By downloading and using the CUDA Toolkit conda packages, you accept the terms and conditions of the CUDA End User License Agreement (EULA): [https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/eula/index.html"](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/eula/index.html%22)

done
ERROR conda.core.link:_execute(745): An error occurred while installing package 'conda-forge::cudatoolkit-11.2.2-h933977f_10'.
Rolling back transaction: done

LinkError: post-link script failed for package conda-forge::cudatoolkit-11.2.2-h933977f_10
location of failed script: C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\tf_gpu\Scripts.cudatoolkit-post-link.bat
==> script messages <==
"By downloading and using the CUDA Toolkit conda packages, you accept the terms and conditions of the CUDA End User License Agreement (EULA): [https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/eula/index.html"](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/eula/index.html%22)

==> script output <==
stdout:
stderr: 'chcp' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'chcp' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'chcp' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

return code: 1

()
"""

I have been trying for days to use my gpu with tensorflow but I couldn't.

Comment: What is the GPU model? What is your OS? Have you installed [CudaToolKit](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-toolkit-archive) and [cudNN](https://developer.nvidia.com/rdp/cudnn-archive). Also try to run the ```nvidia-smi``` command. Also check if cuda path is added to environment variables.

Comment: yes I have downloaded the latest versions of cudnn and cuda on my machine and added them to environment variable on path but still not wokring and I have tried to run nvidia-smi and nvcc and both works fine

Comment: I have windows 10 forgot to say that and my gpu is gtx 1660 super

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem with other packages, and below worked for me.

The main problem is with `chcp` is not recognized as an internal or external command" as Conda doesn't have access to `chcp` command.

*SOLUTION:*

Add to your PATH environment variable: `C:\Windows\System32` and `%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem` so the command 'chcp' can work form wherever.

You can check if `chcp` command works, by opening command line (not as administrator) and checking if command `where chcp` gives you some result.

I taken the solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8142058/chcp-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command-operable-program-or) and [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1538982/stderr-chcp-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command-operable-pr).

Comment: Thank you so much it worked and I was able to download cudatoolkit and cudnn, but sadly still not detecting my gpu